# Protocol buffer to SWIFT message conversation

Tags: protocol-buffers, messaging

Sorry if this question look very vague.

My requirement is to to generate swift MT543 message from incoming Google protocol buffer message format. Just want to understand if we have any existing framework for GPB which can help here like we have xslt for xml.

I tried googling around it but couldn't find any thing useful.

Comment: My expectation here would be that you need to apply a "deserialize with library A, map (manually or automated) from A's type model to B's type model, serialize with library B" approach - not elegant, but also not all that messy